# jQuery indexing divs for prev/next navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, navigation, jquery-selectors

I wonder if it's possible to create something like a prev/next navigation with jQuery where it indexes all the divs with the same class.  To try this I created a pretty basic fiddle.

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#" class="prevtrigger">PREV</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nexttrigger">NEXT</a></li>
</ul>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="box">1</div>
                <div class="box">2</div>
                <div class="box">3</div>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="box">4</div>
                <div class="box">5</div>
                <div class="box">6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I also created a basic jQuery action changing the color of the boxes:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

     $('.prevtrigger').click(function(){
                  $( '.box' ).css("background-color", "blue")
     });

    $('.nexttrigger').click(function(){
                  $( '.box' ).css("background-color", "green")
     });

});
```

Now the question is: how do I manage to color one div after another red or green depending on the actual index it has. Ideas anyone? Have a look at my fiddle: [HERE!](http://jsfiddle.net/mleyendecker/74Swa/15/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at following jQuery functions:

- prev()
- next()

Example:

```
$(".box.active").prev().css("background-color", "blue" );
$(".box.active").next().css("background-color", "green");
```

You could add a "active" class to the current element and use the prev and next function to make the switch.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74Swa/20/)

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I'm somehow stuck. Adding a "active" class seems to make sense, but how would you realize it? Seems like I don't really get it right now :D

Comment: Yeah, guess I just needed a break, thank you!
I try to implement this on the 'bigger' project (a portfolio I'm working on) but I can't reproduce this - can you see my mistake?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mleyendecker/632Fw/105/

Comment: What I mean by 'mistake' is, that it does not look for all the elements, only those with the same class in one .col-md-6 list div - is there a chance to make it work?